# Best Practices for ASP.NET Webforms Project structure

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When using ASP.NET webforms, I see two main ways to structure a project:

1) Have a lot of .aspx files (including code behind files) and maybe some .ascx files (with code behind files.

2) Rely on a lot of .cs files (class files), and have the classes construct everything with Controls.Add(), etc.

The first method above results in a lot of aspx and ascx files and very few .cs files.  The second method above results in a lot of .cs files, but very fewer aspx and ascx files.

Is there a "best practices" way to structure project?  Does Microsoft recommend one of these techniques? Is there any information on which of the two styles is used more commonly?

Comment: Very opinionated question, I'm afraid this doesn't fit SO at all... There's no definite answer here, because there's no best practices when it comes to structuring a project... There may be some guidelines or recommendations, but the final decision is always on you. Go with the approach you feel most comfortable with. I suggest reading this for starters - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Have a look at **http://www.bredemeyer.com/why.htm** and **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658093**

Answer (score 3):

I would stick with the first approach. Some controls are extremely tedious (or difficult) to be created progamatically.

Take the `GridView` or `ListView` for example, create an *.aspx page with a GridView which has custom templates with template columns. Then run your application, find the *.dll in the ASP.NET temp directory, decompile the class and look how messy and complicated is the code. It would be very difficult to maintain it over time and/or make changes.

On the other hand, having some declarative code isn't bad as long as you try to maintain the balance.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done so, check out [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). If you cannot opt for MVC you can implement [MVP pattern](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MVP+pattern+with+ASP.NET+WebForms) with ASP.NET WebForms. These two patterns provide good way to separate presentation, model and routing.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with either approach.  Which one you use depends on personal preference, feasibility, and requirements.

One issue you may face is that fewer developers will be able to pick up your project and run with it if you use the second approach, or will take much longer to get up to speed with it.  You will find a lot more developers that can easily pick up the first approach and go.

Answer (score 0):

Use approach one as much as possible and only resort to approach two when the out of the box controls do not give you the functionality you require - you can create a custom control by inheriting from an existing control in this case. This is not an "either/or" scenario - you should use both approaches judiciously.